# LINQ instead of nested foreach and if

Tags: c#, linq

Does anyone knows what the Linq code is for the following code?:

```
foreach (Bed bed in field.GetBeds())
{
    foreach (Asparagus asparagus in bed.GetAsparaguses())
    {
        if (asparagus.Time.Date == day.Date && asparagus.Harvested)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try ReSharper tool and it will help you to learn LINQ quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use `SelectMany` to flatten out the nested items.

```
var count = field.BetBeds()
    .SelectMany(bed => bed.GetAsparaguses())
    .Where(asparagus => asparagus.Time.Date == day.Date && asparagus.Harvested)
    .Count();
```

Comment: `.Count(a=> a.Time.Date == day.Date && a.Harvested)`

Answer (score 1):

By `SelectMany` to get all asparaguses, filter them by the conditions in `Where` and `Count` the result

```
field.GetBeds()
     .SelectMany(bed => bed.GetAsparaguses())
     .Where(asparagus => asparagus.Time.Date == day.Date && asparagus.Harvested)
     .Count();
```